# Получить fragment из Activity?

Tags: java, android

Есть вот такая задача.

Есть два фаргмента.
`fragment1` = 3 кнопки
`fragment2` = текстовое поле.

Хочу что бы они взаимодействовали друг с другом через Activity.

Сделал следующее.
В первом фрагменте на каждую кнопку повесил слушатели по клику, где и сохраняется индекс кнопки. вот код.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

        return  rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int buttonIndex = getIndex(v.getId());    
    }      

    public int getIndex(int id){
        int index = -1;

        if (id==R.id.button) {
            index = 1 ;
        }
        if (id==R.id.button2) {
            index = 2 ;
        }
        if (id==R.id.button3) {
            index = 3 ;
        }    

        return index;
    }
```

во втором фрагменте ничего сложного, просто вставляют текст из массива. Есть один метод.

```
public void setDiscription(int index){    
        String text = mCatDescriptionArray[index];    
        textView.setText(text);    
    }
```

А как теперь активити узнает что я нажал по кнопке в первом фрагменте, и в этот момент мне надо поменять текст во втором фрагменте?

Comment: Через интерфейсы, конечно:) Щас дам ответ

Comment: Да вот где то я читал, но что то не получается, подскажите как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Создаем интерфейс FragmentButtonListener.

```
public interface FragmentButtonListener{
   void buttonClicked(int buttonIndex);
}
```

В первом фрагменте добавляешь переменную листенера и делаешь сеттер на него

```
private FragmentButtonListener listener;

public void setListener(FragmentButtonListener listener){
   this.listener = listener;
}
```

В своем активити:

```
public class YourActivity extends WhateverExtends implements FragmentButtonListener{

@Override
public void buttonClicked(int buttonIndex){
   showSecondFragment(buttonIndex);
}

public void showSecondFragment(int buttonIndex){
   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
   Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putInt("buttonIndex", buttonIndex);
   fragment.setArguments(args);
   ft.replace(R.id.YourContainerId, fragment);
   // если нужно, то в backstack кидаешь
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.commit();
}
```

Ах да, не забудьте повесить listener, когда вызываете первый фрагмент:

```
   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
   Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment();
   firstFragment.setListener(this);
   ft.replace(R.id.YourContainerId, fragment);
   // если нужно, то в backstack кидаешь
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.commit();
```

И уже во втором фрагменте, в любой момент времени, вы можете получить этот индекс:

```
Bundle data = getArguments();
int pressedBtnIndex = data.getInt("buttonIndex");
```

Дальше уже делаете с этими данными что хотите. Как-то так

UPD: забыл. Нужно еще при клике вызывать метод листенера, конечно же.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int buttonIndex = getIndex(v.getId());
    listener.buttonClicked(buttonIndex);
}
```

Comment: Блин че то много чего запутался(((( у вас есть скайп? мне очень хочется решить эту проблему((((

Comment: @duddeniska укажите в чем проблема, просто:) Если мы решим вашу проблему в скайпе, то другим она видна не будет. Лучше тут. Скиньте логи. Еще лучше - скиньте ваш код, который получился

Comment: Не могу понять просто, я создал интерфейс                                     public interface OnSelectedButtonListener {
        void onButtonSelected(int buttonIndex);
    } в главном активити я его описываю, в данном случае я меняю текст, но в какой момент в главном активити он поймет что я нажал кнопку, у меня нету в главном активити метода Onclick

Comment: @duddeniska как это нету?)) Вы же сами сказали, что описали onButtonSelected)) Когда вы нажимаете на кнопку в первом фрагменте, вы вызываете метод листенера. В данном случае, листенер - это ваше активити. Вы вызываете метод активити. Не забыли сделать setListener(this); для первого фрагмента?

Comment: setListener где именно сделать? в методе onclick в первом фрагменте? или в Активити в методе onButtonSelected?

Comment: @duddeniska когда создается первый фрагмент. Я дополнил ответ. там, где setListener(), теперь больше кода. Надеюсь, так понятнее будет

Comment: listener.buttonClicked(buttonIndex); ошибка в этой строке. В дебаге посмотрел listener у меня равен == null

Comment: @duddeniska покажите свой код. setListener и вызов первого фрагмента.

Comment: Не лучшая идея, хранить ссылку на Activity во фрагменте. Если уж так и делать, то нужно не забывать сбрасывать ее в onDetach() фрагмента. Надежнее было бы сделать как у гугла в примерах: if(getActivity() instanceof FragmentButtonListener) ((FragmentButtonListener)getActivity()).buttonClicked(buttonIndex);

Comment: @Ganster41 вы абсолютно правы:) Позже подправлю ответ

Answer (score 1):

Взаимодействие между фрагментами и активити описано в этой статье - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

А для того, чтобы сказать второму фрагменту что надо обновить текстовое поле, просто ищем фрагмент по тегу и если вернулся не `null` то пытаемся привести этот фрагмент к нашему, после чего вызываем метод `setDiscription(int index)`
Примерно так

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
if(currentFragment != null && currentFragment instanceof Fragment2){
        Fragment2 fragment2 = (Fragment2)currentFragment;               
        fragment2.setDiscription(index);
}
```